# TSQL Manager Hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I need to be able to show all my managers in a hierarchy in different columns. I don't know how many levels there will be.

Example: **Employee – ManagerOfEmployee - TheBigBoss**

I have tried the below but cant get it to work the way I want it.

I need the results to look like this:

```
Level1Column   Level2Column   Level3Column
------------------------------------------
     1              2              3
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblHRData
(
    Emplid          INT,
    ReportsToEmplid INT
)

INSERT INTO #tblHRData (Emplid, ReportsToEmplid)
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 3)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
        Emplid,
        ReportsToEmplid,
        1 AS level
    FROM    
        #tblHRData
    WHERE   
        Emplid = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  
        child.Emplid,
        child.ReportsToEmplid,
        level + 1
    FROM    
        #tblHRData child
    JOIN    
        CTE parent ON child.ReportsToEmplid = parent.Emplid
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: You need a dynamic pivot.

Comment: i think, this should be done in presentation layer...

Answer (score 0):

With an *unknown depth* you will have to go the *dynamic SQL route*. But such cases tend to have a maximal depth. As your columns will have *computable names*, you can try this:

I enhanced your table a bit:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblHRData
(
    Emplid          INT,
    ReportsToEmplid INT,
    Descr           VARCHAR(100) 
)

INSERT INTO #tblHRData (Emplid, ReportsToEmplid, Descr)
VALUES (1, 2, 'lvl 3.2.1') --boss is 2
      ,(2, 3, 'lvl 3.2')   --boss is 3
      ,(3,null, 'big boss')--big boss reports to no one
      ,(4, 3, 'lvl 3.4')   --one more 2nd lvl
      ,(5, 4, 'lvl 3.4.5') --below 4
      ,(6, 4, 'lvl 3.4.6') --another one below 4
```

-- And I changed the recursive CTE to start off with the *big boss* and to build a sort string *on the fly*. In this case this is limited to 3 digits. You'll have to widen this with `Emplid`s exceeding `999`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
        Emplid,
        ReportsToEmplid,
        Descr,
        0 AS EmpLvl,
        CAST(REPLACE(STR(Emplid,3),' ','0') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SortOrder
    FROM    
        #tblHRData
    WHERE   
        ReportsToEmplid IS NULL --start with the big boss

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  
        child.Emplid,
        child.ReportsToEmplid,
        child.Descr,
        parent.EmpLvl + 1,
        parent.SortOrder + REPLACE(STR(child.Emplid,3),' ','0')
    FROM    
        #tblHRData child
    JOIN    
        CTE parent ON child.ReportsToEmplid = parent.Emplid
)
SELECT Emplid,
       SortOrder, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN EmpLvl=0 THEN Descr END) AS BossDescr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EmpLvl=1 THEN Descr END) AS Lvl1Descr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EmpLvl=2 THEN Descr END) AS Lvl2Descr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EmpLvl=3 THEN Descr END) AS Lvl3Descr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EmpLvl=4 THEN Descr END) AS Lvl4Descr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EmpLvl=5 THEN Descr END) AS Lvl5Descr
       --add as many as you need and add some more to be future safe
FROM CTE
GROUP BY EmpLvl,Emplid,SortOrder
ORDER BY SortOrder;
GO
DROP TABLE #tblHRData
```

The result

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Emplid | SortOrder | BossDescr | Lvl1Descr | Lvl2Descr | Lvl3Descr | Lvl4Descr | Lvl5Descr |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3      | 003       | big boss  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2      | 003002    | NULL      | lvl 3.2   | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      | 003002001 | NULL      | NULL      | lvl 3.2.1 | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 4      | 003004    | NULL      | lvl 3.4   | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 5      | 003004005 | NULL      | NULL      | lvl 3.4.5 | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 6      | 003004006 | NULL      | NULL      | lvl 3.4.6 | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Some remarks:
 - I use the *conditional aggregation* as `PIVOT` approach. With just one column this can be done with `PIVOT()` too.
 - The `SortOrder` is important to be created in the recursion. It is kind of *the path to the entry* and will allow you to order your result-set.
 - This *path* must allow alphanumerical sorting. Therefore I concatenate padded strings.